# Access MS SQL Server with ntlm authentication from .net core app on linux

Tags: .net, linux, asp.net-core

I have asp.net core app that connect to MS SQL Server using Integrated Security.
This works fine on windows, but when deployed to linux, Integrated security feature doesn't work and this is obvious.
I do not use EF or other orms, just simple System.Data.SqlClient

SO the question is how to access MS SQL Server database with domain authentication from asp.net core app on linux?
This sql server doesn't support sql authorization, so we cant just use userid and password in out connection string.

Many languages like GO for example supports ntml in ther sql clients. How to do it on .net core?

Comment: You forgot to mention the database Framwork/library you work with. EntityFramework 6? EfCore? ADO.NET? Dapper? Mssql client?

Comment: fixed. I do not use any ORMs. Just System.Data.SqlClient

Comment: You can't. For ASP.NET Core Integrated Auth requires IIS, thus it's only available on Windows.

Comment: I understand it. But are there any workaroud?

Comment: No. There's no workaround. Which is why I said "You can't"

Answer (score 0):

Since some time this can be done. The details are important, but the important parts are:

**Install kerberos stuff**

> apt install -y krb5-config
>
> apt-get install -y krb5-user

**Create krb5.conf file**

see link below for details

**Generate keytab file**

> ktutil
>
> ktutil: add_entry -password -p myUserName@MY.COMPANY.LOCAL -k 1 -e RC4-HMAC
>   --ktutil will prompt for entering the password ...
>
> ktutil: write_kt myUserName.keytab
>
> ktutil: exit

But there is much more to it, please see [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1272546/Authenticate-NET-Core-Client-of-SQL-Server-with-In) article for all the details.

Answer (score 0):

NTLM auth is not supported in official SqlClient package https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/143

However, a talent guy provided a temporary solution here https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/31

BTW, I don't think Kerberos is a good way because it set the identity of the whole application rather than connection level.